# assigning variables and using in gsub

Tags: awk, gsub

I have a file like this with 12 fields

```
LINE1 CC CC CC CG CG CG CG BRE CC GG CG 
LINE2 GG AA AA AA AA AA AA BRH AA GG AG
LINE3 HH HH HL LL LL LL LL BGH LL HH HL
```

and I want to assign three variables `X=$10`, `y=$11`, `z=$12`. I then want to replace fields 2 - 8 with another value depending on which of my variables they match (when matching x sub with 1, when matching y sub with 2, and when matching  z sub with 3). Note: The variables change each line.

This is what the file should look like

```
LINE1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 BRE CC GG CG 
LINE2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 BRH AA GG AG
LINE3 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 BGH LL HH HL
```

This is what I have tried

```
awk '{x="$10; y="$11"; z="$12; gsub(/x/, "1") && gsub(/y/, "2") && gsub(/z/, "3"); print $0}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this does what you want:

```
$ awk '{for (i=2;i<=8;i++) $i=($i==$10)?1:($i==$11)?2:($i==$12)?3:$i; print}' file
LINE1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 BRE CC GG CG
LINE2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 BRH AA GG AG
LINE3 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 BGH LL HH HL
```

#### How it works

We want to do the substitutions only for fields 2 through 8.  Therefore, we loop over them in turn:

- `for (i=2;i<=8;i++) $i=($i==$10)?1:($i==$11)?2:($i==$12)?3:$i`

  This command loops over each field `i`, from 2 to 8, one at a time.  For each field, `$i` is replaced with 1 if `$i==$10` or else 2 if `$i==$11` or else 3 if `$i==$12` or else it is left unchanged as `$i`.

  This logic is implemented with three 'ternary' statements.  In `awk`, a ternary statement looks like:

  ```
  ($i==$12)?3:$i
  ```

  The first part, `($i==$12)`, is a condition.  If it is true, then the statement returns the value after the `?`.  If it is false, then it returns the value after the `:`.  Thus, if `$i` is equal to `$12`, this statement returns a value of `3`, otherwise it returns the value of `$i`.  The logic above chains three such statements together.
- `print`

  The new line is printed.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{for(i=10;i<=12;++i){for(x=2;x<=8;++x){if($i==$x){$x=i-9}}};print}'  file
```

EDIT: here is a smarter solution using sub function

```
awk '{for(i=10;i<=12;++i){for(x=2;x<=8;++x){if($i==$x){sub($x,i-9,$x)}}};print}'  file
```

Comment: Shorter way `awk '{for(j=1;j<NF-2;j++)for(i=NF-2;i<=NF;++i)sub($i,i-9,$j)}1'`

Comment: @JID indeed yours is shorter :D